# How to auto insert a string in filename by bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the output file day by day:

```
linux-202105200900-foo.direct.tar.gz
```

The date and time string, ex: `202105200900` will change every day.

I need to manually rename these files to

```
linux-202105200900x86-foo.direct.tar.gz
```

( insert a short string `x86` after date/time )

any bash script can help to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're always inserting the string "x86" at character #18 in the string, you may use that command:

```
var="linux-202105200900-foo.direct.tar.gz"
var2=${var:0:18}"x86"${var:18}
echo $var2
```

The 2nd line means: "assign to variable var2 the first 18 characters of var, followed by x86 followed by the rest of the variable var"

If you want to insert "x86" just before the last hyphen in the string, you may write it like this:

```
var="linux-202105200900-foo.direct.tar.gz"
var2=${var%-*}"x86-"${var##*-}
echo $var2
```

The 2nd line means: "assign to variable var2:

- the content of the variable var after removing the shortest matching pattern "-*" at the end
- the string "x86-"
- the content of the variable var after removing the longest matching pattern "*-" at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the very good answer by [@Jean-Loup Sabatier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15203219/jean-loup-sabatier) another, perhaps more general way would simply be to replace the second occurrence of `'-'` with `x86-` which you can do with `sed`. Let's say you have:

```
fname=linux-202105200900-foo.direct.tar.gz
```

You can update that with:

```
fname="$(sed 's/-/x86-/2' <<< "$fname")"
```

Which simply uses a command substitution with `sed` and a *herestring* to modify `fname` assigning the modified result back to `fname`.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ fname=linux-202105200900-foo.direct.tar.gz
fname="$(sed 's/-/x86-/2' <<< "$fname")"
echo $fname
linux-202105200900x86-foo.direct.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to go as simple as possible, considering only the timestamp is going to change, this script should do it. Just run it inside the folder where files are located and you'll get all of them renamed with `x86`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(ls); do
  replaced=$(echo $file | sed 's|-foo|x86-foo|g')
  mv $file $replaced
done
```

This is my output

```
filip@filip-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-1:~/test$ ls
linux-202105200900-foo.direct.tar.gz  linux-202105201000-foo.direct.tar.gz  linux-202105201100-foo.direct.tar.gz
filip@filip-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-1:~/test$ ./../development/bash-utils/bulk-rename.sh 
filip@filip-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-1:~/test$ ls
linux-202105200900x86-foo.direct.tar.gz  linux-202105201000x86-foo.direct.tar.gz  linux-202105201100x86-foo.direct.tar.gz
```

Simply iterate through all the files in current folder and pipeline result to `sed` to replace regex `-foo` with `x86-foo`, then rename file with `mv` command.

As David mentioned in comment, if you're worried that there could be multiple occurrences of `-foo` then you can just replace `g` as global to `1` as first occurrence and that's it!

Comment: Ooh, you are thinking along the right lines, but what if there are two occurrences of `-foo`? (may want to omit the `'g'` (global) replacement scope)  Nice use of the alternate `'|'` delimiters for the `sed` substitution.

Comment: Sure, it can be changed in case if OP is expecting this case, judging by the question it doesn't seem like he cares about this. I can add it to the response I guess.

Comment: No worries, just something that caught my eye looking over it.

Comment: @Filip : Aside from your risky use of `$(ls)`, where a simple `*` would do as well and is safe, and the risky omission of quotes around your variables,  you are processing **all** files in the directory, and even if a file does not have the substring `-foo`, you would execute a `mv`. Of course this would not change the filename, but it would cause a nasty error message on stdout, pointing out that source and destination are the same file.

Comment: True, I'm far from being proficient at bash. Didn't know I could use `*` like that, thanks for that! I know that omission of quotes around my variables is risky, but forgot it because, well I'm not frequent user. And last thing is definitely something that should be done, if you want to do it properly, or if you expect something like that, which is not mentioned in the question, so I just assumed those are the only files in folder. Thanks for the comment, definitely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

```
❯ dat=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'); echo ${dat}
20210520170336
❯ filename="linux-${dat}x86-foo.direct.tar.gz"; echo ${filename}
linux-20210520170336x86-foo.direct.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the rename utility (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), you could use:

```
rename -v 0-foo.direct.tar.gz 0x86-foo.direct.tar.gz *
```

which results in

```
`linux-202105200900-foo.direct.tar.gz' -> `linux-202105200900x86-foo.direct.tar.gz'
`linux-202205200900-foo.direct.tar.gz' -> `linux-202205200900x86-foo.direct.tar.gz'
`linux-202305200900-foo.direct.tar.gz' -> `linux-202305200900x86-foo.direct.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the very good answer by @David C. Rankin, just adding it in a loop and renaming the files

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
for file in `ls linux* 2>/dev/null` # Extract all  files starting with linux
do
echo $file
fname="$(sed 's/-/x86-/2' <<< "$file")"
mv "$file" "$fname"                 # Rename file 
done
```

Output recieved : 
`linux-202105200900x86-foo.direct.tar.gz`